# Select2 add onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using vuexy theme in my Laravel project. I want to add onchange to the select2 input I'm using, but I couldn't.

My select2;

```html
<div class="col-12 mb-2">
  <label class="form-label" for="personalSelect">Personel</label>
  <select class="select2 form-select" id="personalSelect" name="personal_id" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Personel Seçiniz</option>
    @foreach ($savedPersonals as $personals)
    <option value="{{ $personals->id }}">{{ $personals->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```js
$('#personalSelect').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: Do you want a _change_, or a _select_ handler?

Comment: What version of Select2 are you using? The JS events differ in older versions compared to newer ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize Select2 manually:

```html
<select class="form-select" id="personalSelect" name="personal_id" required>
```

```js
$('#personalSelect').select2().on('select2:select', function(e) {
  console.log("test");
});
```